# How to make a dataGenerator (for non-image-data) in KERAS API model for multiple inputs?

Tags: keras, dynamic, generator, numpy-ndarray, multiple-input

I want to input four 2D NumPy arrays (Non-image-data). Now, I want to load to data dynamically as number of samples is huge. How can I do it in Keras?
Thanks in advance.